# Navigation destination com.example.multimodulepoc:id/navigation_home is not a direct child of this NavGraph

Tags: android, navigation, android-jetpack-navigation

I'm trying to add navigation of  multiple modules in the app using  tag I've provided my startDestination from `home` module. Its working fine when I've only one `<include>` tag with startDestination. App getting crash with following error message when I added multiple module navigations. I found no useful links in SO. Please help us to resolve this issue. Thanks in advance.

```
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: navigation destination com.example.multimodulepoc:id/navigation_home is not a direct child of this NavGraph
```

Below is my navigation xml and dependency.

```
app build.gradle.

dependencies {
    ....
    implementation project( ':home')
    implementation project( ':Dashobard')
    ....
}
```

App level Navigation xml.

```
<navigation xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/mobile_navigation"
    app:startDestination="@id/navigation_home">

    <include app:graph="@navigation/home_navigation" />
    <include app:graph="@navigation/dashboard_navigation" />

</navigation>
```

Home module Navigation

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<navigation xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/home_navigation"
    app:startDestination="@+id/navigation_home">
    <fragment
        android:id="@+id/navigation_home"
        android:name="com.ns.mpos.home.home.HomeFragment"
        android:label="@string/title_home"
        tools:layout="@layout/fragment_home" />
</navigation>
```

Dashboard Navigation

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<navigation xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/dashboard_navigation"
    app:startDestination="@+id/navigation_dashboard">

    <fragment
        android:id="@+id/navigation_dashboard"
        android:name="com.ns.mpos.dashobard.dashboard.DashboardFragment"
        android:label="@string/title_dashboard"
        tools:layout="@layout/fragment_dashboard" />

</navigation>
```

Comment: So what is the `android:id` on the root element of your `@navigation/home_navigation` graph? Please include that XML file as well.

Comment: Hi @Ianhanniballke Thanks for responding, Updated the question as your request.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'faced similar crash if trying to navigate another module navigation.

```
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Navigation action/destination com.example.multimodulepoc:id/navigation_dashboard cannot be found from the current destination Destination(com.example.multimodulepoc:id/navigation_home) label=Home class=com.example.home.home.HomeFragment
```

With the help of @ianhanniballake comments, Fixed the crash with following code helps me to resolve the crash.

```
findNavController().setGraph(R.navigation.dashboard_navigation)
findNavController().navigate(R.id.navigation_dashboard)
```

Comment: I think you should mark ianhanniballake's answer as accepted if it solved your problem.

Answer (score 1):

Your home module graph has:

```
<navigation xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/home_navigation"
```

So the ID of your home graph is `@id/home_navigation` but that's not the ID you've set as the `startDestination` of your app level graph, hence the error message:

```
navigation destination com.example.multimodulepoc:id/navigation_home is not a direct child of this NavGraph
```

The 'direct child' is the most important part here: your app level graph has no knowledge of the destinations within your home graph, just the graph itself. Therefore, you need to ensure that the `startDestination` of your app level graph actually matches the `android:id` of your home graph:

```
<navigation xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/mobile_navigation"
    app:startDestination="@id/home_navigation">

    <include app:graph="@navigation/home_navigation" />
    <include app:graph="@navigation/dashboard_navigation" />

</navigation>
```

Comment: Hi @ianhanniballake, Thanks for posting the answer, issue has been fixed for home_navigation. But facing same error if the navigating to different    navigation graph

Comment: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Navigation action/destination com.ns.mpos.multimodulepoc:id/navigation_dashboard cannot be found from the current destination Destination(com.ns.mpos.multimodulepoc:id/navigation_home) label=Home class=com.ns.mpos.home.home.HomeFragment

Comment: Again, you don't have visibility into the inner destinations within the other graph - just the graph itself. It sounds like you should be navigating to the graph's id: `dashboard_navigation`